# combine two xml kml documents using python and minidom

Tags: python, kml, minidom, kmz

I have a script which generates kmz files for a set of items that the user sends in. i want to take a specific section from each kml (xml) document and push it into a single kml document.

So what i get in each loop is a kmz document that i then extract to doc.kml and inside of that there is a Document node near the top. I want to take everything under the document node and jam it into a single kml file.

Instead of

```
<document>stuff1</document>
<document>stuff2</document>
<document>stuff3</document>
```

I want to wind up with

```
<document>
stuff1
stuff2
stuff3
</document>
```

Here is what i have so far

```
kmz = ZipFile(outKML + str(x) + ".kmz", 'r')
arcpy.AddMessage("extracting kmz")
kmz.extractall()
kml = kmz.open('doc.kml', 'r')


#if this is the first doc.kml then we will use that for the source

if x == 0:
    dom1 = parse(kml)
    #doc1 = dom1.getElementsByTagName("Document")[0]
    #print doc1.toprettyxml()

else:
    dom2 = parse(kml)
    #doc2 = dom2.getElementsByTagName("Document")[0]
    #print doc2.toprettyxml()


    imp = dom1.importNode(dom2.childNodes[0],True)
    dom1.childNodes[0].appendChild(imp) 
    print dom1.toprettyxml()        

x = x + 1
```

I feel like i am close but am struggling mightily with minidom. I can't seem to find the reference docs that tell me exactly what importNode does.
The code i have now appends the entire document below the current document. Close but i don't want two document tags, just one.

Comment: `<document>stuff1stuff2stuff3</document>` so this is what you want? it seems like useless xml to me, so i am asking just to be sure?

Comment: yes. and right now i get <document>stuff1</document><document>stuff2</document>

Comment: the kmz format only needs the one document header and then you can cram what you want below that

Comment: maybe another way to phrases this is - can i use minidom or etree to insert xml into xml? I don't want to create new tags, just plug existing xml into the dom